# Restrict Access for users on Leave

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

How to restrict access to salesforce application for the time users are on leave on basis of Leave start and end date?
Freeze user on leave start date and then unfreeze on leave end date ?
Any other automation approach ?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you want to achieve? Nightly batch job that does either of these should be enough? Not sure if you can do time-basrd workflows/processes on users.

You can (de)activate them although it's bit of a nuclear option. Other users might be impacted when they work with deactivated users' data, "operation was performed with inactive user" error.

You can (un)freeze manually or by modifying UserLogin table, each user will have 1 record in it. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userlogin.htm

If you want them to be able to log in but do limited set of things - you could look at your sharing rules and temp change their role/group/whatever. Or change profile to read-only. Or unassign a permission set.

Then there are more sophisticated things like maybe disabling their SSO, having a login flow that checks something on user record, checking up addresses (like allow login only from office network, not from home). You could look into "high assurance sessions", multi factor authentication (take their work phone or RSA device when they go on holidays?) or there's interesting trailhead about detecting / preventing suspicious activity. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/enhanced_transaction_security and https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring